# What does the MySQL "max_allowed_packet" setting actually control?

Tags: mysql, packet

We've been cleaning up database problems for the last four hours, thanks to a broken `mysqldump` that wasn't sufficiently erroring out.  We were getting these errors:

```
mysqldump: Error 2020: Got packet bigger than "max_allowed_packet" bytes when dumping table "search_dataset" at row: 68014
```

What the heck does that setting do?  It's obviously not IP packet size, since I have it set to 32M now.  Why does it exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [page 99 of "Understanding MySQL Internals" (ISBN 0-596-00957-7)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596009577), here are paragraphs 1-3 explaining it:

> MySQL network communication code was
>   written under the assumption that
>   queries are always reasonably short,
>   and therefore can be sent to and
>   processed by the server in one chunk,
>   which is called a *packet* in MySQL
>   terminology. The server allocates the
>   memory for a temporary buffer to store
>   the packet, and it requests enough to
>   fit it entirely. This architecture
>   requires a precaution to avoid having
>   the server run out of memory---a cap
>   on the size of the packet, which this
>   option accomplishes.
>
> The code of interest in relation to
>   this option is found in
>   **sql/net_serv.cc**. Take a look at **my_net_read()**, then follow the call to **my_real_read()** and pay
>   particular attention to
>   **net_realloc()**.
>
> This variable also limits the length
>   of a result of many string functons.
>   See **sql/field.cc** and
>   **sql/intem_strfunc.cc** for details.

This is probably the most complete explanation of max_allowed_packet I have ever seen. I typed those 3 paragraphs right from the book.

Comment: Thanks for posting that.  It seems to hint that "packet" means "IP packet."

Comment: Great answer. I guess this is as close as I'm getting to a real answer. (I'm still pretty sure this isn't referring to IP packets. It doesn't mention IP anywhere, and I believe 65535 bytes is typically the real-world limit for even fragmented IP packets.)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation explains it in full detail here:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet

"The maximum size of one packet or any generated/intermediate string. ..."

The documentation also goes on to address BLOBs and how this setting ties into them.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. What's a packet in this context? Is it actually an IP packet? Isn't there a better way than a simple byte limit to catch malformed data?

Comment: Unless they define "packet" as being something else (which they don't appear to do in the documentation), it is reasonable to expect that "packet" refers to an IP packet.

Comment: I found the definition in a book I have. I added an excerpt from that book as my answer.