# Network connection to server lost, but not to internet

Tags: windows-7, networking, mysql, switch

I have a network with four computers, each running Windows 7. All of them are connected to a central switch.
My problem is that the internal network connection is lost very often, although internet connectivity works fine. This usually happens while using a management software that runs with MySQL database. This program is installed in the server.
The support department of this software tells me that their software works like it should, and that the issue is caused by my network, but I haven't been able to figure out the problem and the network seems to work OK.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related: [Windows 7 losing connection to network but not internet - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/456113/windows-7-losing-connection-to-network-but-not-internet)

Comment: Which laptop do you have?

Answer (score 0):

## MySQL PERSPECTIVE

It sounds like you might be the victim of the MySQL's silent killer: The MySQL Packet.

MySQL has its own internal layer for the purpose of packing and transmitting data that is not often discussed. I wrote a SuperUser post 3 years ago describing what and how a MySQL Packet is used. I have also I have used it in posts in the DBA StackExchange

- `Apr 21, 2011` : [What does the MySQL "max_allowed_packet" setting actually control?](https://superuser.com/questions/273730/what-does-the-mysql-max-allowed-packet-setting-actually-control/273833#273833)
- `Sep 01, 2011` : [MySQL server has gone away obstructing import of large dumps](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5292/mysql-server-has-gone-away-obstructing-import-of-large-dumps/5323#5323)
- `Sep 25, 2011` : [Fixing MySQL errors recorded in error logs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6134/fixing-mysql-errors-recorded-in-error-logs/6149#6149)
- `Jun 12, 2012` : [MySQL Error Reading Communication Packets](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19135/mysql-error-reading-communication-packets/19139#19139)

## SUGGESTION

Locate the error log for MySQL and see if there are any packet errors listed.

If the error log is not enabled, then enable it in the `my.ini`. In terms of the MySQL Packet itself, you may need to increase it in `my.ini` as follows:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 1G
```

Don't worry about setting [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) to 1G. When a packet is first initialized, it starts with the size set by [net_buffer_length](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_buffer_length). The [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) is the ceiling cap for the size of the packet.

If you want to increase the packet size dynamically, run this in the mysql command line:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
```

## EPILOGUE

My post is just to have you tune MySQL in this aspect. It may not be the solution if the network is in the habit of dropping packets due to faulty cables or any form of communication noise. Since networking is out of my wheelhouse, I will leave that to more capable members of this forum to address that.